# Use recursion in Java to returns the binary logarithm of a given number

Tags: java, recursion, return

This is the Screenshot of The problem that i'm Solving:

---

[image: screenshot]

---

This is my code, It's working fine but problem is If n<=0 i want to return "Undefined" at the same method But as you can see my method return type is `int`. So how can i do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(recursiveBinaryLog(1));
    System.out.println(recursiveBinaryLog(8));
    System.out.println(recursiveBinaryLog(0));
    System.out.println(recursiveBinaryLog(-2));
}

static int recursiveBinaryLog(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (1 + recursiveBinaryLog(n / 2));
}
```

Comment: if result of `recursiveBinaryLog` is `0`, you can say it `String("Undefined")`

Comment: `String("Undefined")` doesn't mean anything. `"Undefined"` does, and so does `new String("Undefined")`, but the latter is redundant.

Comment: One thing you can do is to return a number that indicates the undefined value, like `-1`. Then you check the returned value. Another thing is to throw an exception, which would be the usual solution.

Comment: If you return `Undefined` when `n <= 0`, you will not be able to compute `recursiveBinaryLog(1)`.

Comment: The standard way to handle `n <= 0` would be to throw an exception, e.g. an `IllegalArgumentException` or an `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: The result for `n = 1` should be 0, but your code return 1, which also means that results for all values of `n > 1` is wrong too.

Comment: @akuzminykh Would you please give more information about first one, how can i  implement by indicating the undefined value(-1) ?

Comment: @Himu21 `if (n <= 0) return -1;` then `if (n == 1) return 0;`. Caller could then check if returned value is `-1` and print `"Undefined"`, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have method `recursiveBinaryLog` return a `String` instead of an `int`, do the recursion in a separate method.

Nothing in the linked problem states that it is the `recursiveBinaryLog` method itself that has to be recursive, only that you have to use recursion to solve the problem, using the given algorithm.

```java
static String recursiveBinaryLog(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return "Undefined";
    return String.valueOf(recursiveBinaryLog0(n));
}

private static int recursiveBinaryLog0(int n) {
    return (n == 1 ? 0 : 1 + recursiveBinaryLog0(n / 2));
}
```

Comment: Why not `return n <= 0 ? "Undefined" : String.valueOf(recursiveBinaryLog0(n));` in the first method? And the parenthesis are redundant in your ternary.

Comment: Maybe return a `double`, not a `String`, there is the value `NaN` which is also pretty much undefined.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Answer to both is: Personal style. --- I didn't use ternary conditional operator because the line got too long and I didn't like it. --- I always use parenthesis around ternary conditional operator to prevent operator precedence misunderstandings, since the `? :` operators have so very low [precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/), that only assignment operators are lower. Defensive habit.

Comment: @dan1st You could, but the result would be misleading, since the result is not a true `double` binary logarithm, since the result is an integer value, not a higher precision decimal value. Besides, the question specifically asked for `String` return type, and this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch As personal style, I also always use parenthesis with boolean expressions. Helps differentiate `a = b = 0;` from `a = b == 0;` when you do `a = (b == 0);`, making the distinction clearer. --- You could argue that ternary operator should then be `(a) ? b : c`, but since I use parenthesis around entire construct, `((a) ? b : c)` would be excessive, so I use `(a ? b : c)`. No extra parenthesis when using multiple, e.g. `(a ? b : c ? d : e ? f : g)` *(inline if-elseif)* and `(a ? b ? c : d : e)`, though I might do `(a ? (b ? c : d) : e)` if the subexpressions are complex.

Comment: Just curious. Since one used the ternary and the other didn't.

Comment: @Andreas  Thank You, Your code is working fine! As i'm a beginner in JAVA so i'm trying to implement different possible answers so that i can learn! I was reading some codes there i found (throw new IllegalArgumentException) so , tried to implement this expression in my code ,unfortunately i'm getting error__ this the code __ 
 `static int recursiveBinaryLog(int n){
  if (n <= 0) 
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Undefined");
  
  return (1 + recursiveBinaryLog(n / 2))`

Comment: @Andreas  This is the error- `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undefined
 at mainPackage.RecursiveBinaryLogTest.recursiveBinaryLog(RecursiveBinaryLogTest.java:17)
 at mainPackage.RecursiveBinaryLogTest.recursiveBinaryLog(RecursiveBinaryLogTest.java:19)
 at mainPackage.RecursiveBinaryLogTest.main(RecursiveBinaryLogTest.java:7)`

Comment: @Himu21 Well, yeah, what did you think throwing an exception means? Your code is throwing an exception, and the program shows that exception having been thrown. What's confusing about that? Perhaps you should go back and reread the section about exceptions in your Java guide.